# Binding Kivy ObjectProperty to a child widget doesn't seem to work outside of root widget

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Trying to follow this guide : https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code

I am attempting to access a widget using an id definition. This works well inside the root widget but it doesn't seem to work outside of it. 
As an example here's a bare minimum code representing my issue :

GUI.kv file :

```
<PlotBox@BoxLayout>:
graph2:graph2_id
BoxLayout:
    id:graph2_id

<RootWidget@BoxLayout>:
    graph:graph_id
    BoxLayout:
        id:graph_id
    PlotBox:
```

python file :

```
#kivy imports
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class PlotBox(BoxLayout):
    graph2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(PlotBox,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.graph2.add_widget(Button(text="This doesn't work"))

class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    graph = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(RootWidget,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.graph.add_widget(Button(text='This works'))

class GUIApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = RootWidget()
        return self.root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUIApp().run()
```

I get the error :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_widget'
```

On the RootWidget, it works even if I don't use graph = ObjectProperty(None).
On my other widget, it's like the id doesn't get created.

Comment: A question here, are you trying to affect the CLASS of PlotBox so all future PlotBoxes will have an added Button or *just* the one instance of the PlotBox on the root widget?

Comment: @AlexAndDraw Just the one instance of the PlotBox on the root widget. I originally had another instance of PlotBox with another widget but not anymore. The widget I add is actually a "FigureCanvasKivyAgg" (from matplotlib garden module) which I don't think can be added through kv, but I used a Button in my example because it's clearer and the end result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#dynamic-classes):

> The @ character is used to separate your class name from the classes you want to subclass. [...]

From what is concluded that it is an equivalent way to do inheritance in the .kv similar to python so you should only select one of those ways. That causes PlotBox from .py to never be invoked.

Another error, according to the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv), I do not know if it's your error but the .kv must be gui.kv, with lowercase.

children are not loaded directly after executing the parent's constructor so adding it in the constructor can generate problems, a recommendation and a very common practice in kivy is to use `Clock`.

All the above I have implemented in the following codes:

**gui.kv**

```
<PlotBox>:
    graph2:graph2_id
    BoxLayout:
        id:graph2_id

<RootWidget>:
    graph:graph_id
    BoxLayout:
        id:graph_id
    PlotBox:
```

**main.py**

```
#kivy imports
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

class PlotBox(BoxLayout):
    graph2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(PlotBox,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.graph2.add_widget(Button(text="This now works")))

class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    graph = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(RootWidget,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.graph.add_widget(Button(text='This works'))

class GUIApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = RootWidget()
        return root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUIApp().run()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Adding Clock fixed it! Thank you! 
As for the upper case kv, it seems to work but I renamed it anyway, and for the inheritance, it seems mandatory in python (otherwise it runs, but the child widget is not added correctly) and optionnal in the kv file (it works when it's in both).

Answer (score 2):

I think `self.graph2` just hasn't been set yet during the `__init__` - the `__init__` has to return before any children can be added.

You can work around this by doing something like `Clock.schedule_once(function_that_adds_the_button, 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working under the assumption that you want this code to run when the app is being created, no later.

kv.

```
<PlotBox>:
    BoxLayout:
        id:graph2_id

<RootWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        id:graph_id
    PlotBox:
        id: plot
```

py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class PlotBox(BoxLayout):
    pass

class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass

class GUIApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = RootWidget()
        # We can add things to the Root during build before we return it
        # This means we add this information before the user sees anything
        root.ids.graph_id.add_widget(Button(text='This works'))
        # See end of answer for more about this
        root.ids.plot.ids.graph2_id.add_widget(Button(text='This works!'))
        return root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUIApp().run()
```

Firstly, you don't need Object Properties to access ids, you can do it through ids or children:

```
self.ids.IDGOESHERE
```

OR

```
self.children[INDEXOFIDGOESHERE]
```

As for this line:

```
    root.ids.plot.ids.graph2_id.add_widget(Button(text='This works!'))
```

Root has an *instance* of the plotbox class with the id 'plot'. The Plot class (and therefore all instances of the plot class) have an instance of the BoxLayout with the id graph that we can access.

So what we're doing is:

Root -> Plot -> Graph2

If we were to add another plotbox with the id 'big_plot', then we could do either what we did before to get one Graph2 or we could get a different graph2 because it belongs to a different instance of the plotbox.

## What we did before

Root -> Plot -> Graph2

## A different id, therefore a different widget.

Root -> big_plot -> Graph2

Unless you're invoking super, you'll rarely need to use the init method in a Kivy Widget Class (or so in my experience anyway).

Edit:

If you're going to access super long addresses repeatedly, you can wrap them in a function to get them.

example:

Not great:

```
def func_one(self):
    newtext = 'new'
    self.ids.IDONE.ids.IDTWO.ids.IDTHREE.ids.IDFOUR.text = newtext

def func_two(self):
    newtext = 'newtwo'
    self.ids.IDONE.ids.IDTWO.ids.IDTHREE.ids.IDFOUR.text = newtext

def func_three(self):
    newtext = 'newthree'
    self.ids.IDSONE.Ids.IDTWO.ids.IDTHREE.ids.IDFOUR.text = newtext
```

Better:

```
def long_address(self):
    return self.ids.IDSONE.ids.IDSTWO.ids.IDTHREE.ids.IDFOUR

def func_one(self):
    newtext = 'new'
    self.long_address().text = newtext

def func_two(self):
   newtext = 'newtwo'
   self.long_address().text = newtext

def func_three(self):
    newtext = 'newthree'
    self.long_address().text = newtext
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know it's also possible this way, this can become cumbersome when the widgets are even more nested though (as this would require more .widget.ids)

Comment: Wrap long addresses you use often in a method so you can call them through that. See my edit at the bottom of my answer for examples.